# What's the Best Way to Query Multiple REST API's and Deliver Relevant Search Results?

Tags: database, rest, api, elasticsearch, full-text-search

My organization has multiple databases that we need to provide search results for. Right now you have to search each database individually. I'm trying to create a web interface that will query all the databases at once and sort the results based upon relevance.

Some of the databases I have direct access to. Others I can only access via a REST API.

My challenge isn't knowing how to query each individual database. I understand how to make API calls. It's how to sort the results by relevance.

On the surface it looks like Elasticsearch would be a good option. Its reverse indexing system seems like a good solution to figuring out which results are going to be the most relevant to our users. It's also super fast.

The problem is that I don't see a way (so far) to include results from an external API into Elasticsearch so it can do its magic.

Is there a better option that I'm not aware of? Or is it possible to have Elasticsearch evaluate the relevance of results from an external API while also including data from its own internal indices?

Answer (score 0):

I did find an answer, although nobody replied. :\

The answer is to use the http_poll plugin with logstash. This will make an API call and injest the results into Elasticsearch.

Answer (score 0):

Another option could be some form of microservices orchestration for the various API calls then merge them into a final result set.